# How do I turn off this isolation valve?

Tags: plumbing, valve, dishwasher

I am struggling to turn off this isolation valve to our dishwasher. I have tried attaching a red plastic handle but when I turn it the handle turns but it doesn't turn off the valve. Any advice would be appreciated.

Patrick[image]

Comment: How nice of you to include a clear, focused picture! You'd be shocked at the number of people who can't be bothered with that little detail...

Answer (score 4):

A pair of pliers should work if it turns.  Slip joint pliers might be nicer to hold onto the flat sides.

Comment: An adjustable wrench (spanner) might be even better for the flat surfaces.

Comment: Turn the flat sided stem one quarter turn so the flats are at top and bottom ( with the orientation of the photo). It presently appears to be nearly fully open.

Answer (score 3):

This valve stem was intended to take a metal knob or handle, held with a bolt through the middle. You can get a replacement easily enough. Or, as others have noted, just put a wrench of some sort onto it, though I'd worry about eventually rounding it off that way.

Comment: Often these come with a plastic handle but of course those are more likely to crack than the metal ones. That's probably what happened here.